# Альтернатива repaint(). Как дорисовать линию не стирая старые

Tags: java, gui, graphics

Столкнулся с проблемой еще одной, камушками так-же не бросайтесь пожалуйста. Есть два класса Home

```
public class home {

private JFrame frame;
panel12  fg = new panel12();


public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                home window = new home();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public home() {
    initialize();
}


private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    fg.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
    fg.setBounds(164, 34, 215, 182);
    frame.getContentPane().add(fg);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(22, 49, 89, 23);
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource().equals(btnNewButton)){
                fg.setSw(fg.getSw()+1);
                fg.repaint();// перерисовка графика функции
            }
                }
            });
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);   

    }
}
```

и panel12

```
public class panel12 extends JPanel {
private int sw=1;
public void paint(Graphics g){
super.paint(g);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
switch (sw)
  {
   case 1 :
   funcLine(g);
   break;

   case 2 :
   funcPar(g);
   break;

   case 3 :
   funcGip(g);
   break;
  }
 }

void funcLine(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, 250, 600);
 }

void funcPar(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.drawLine(10, 10, 250, 600);
 }

void funcGip(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawLine(20, 20, 250, 600);
 }

public int getSw() {
      return sw;
     }

public void setSw(int sw) {
    this.sw = sw;
     }
}
```

Проблема в том что `fg.repaint()` перерисовывает заново JPanel, то есть стирает старую линию case 1 и рисует линию из case 2. Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии кнопки оно ДОРИСОВЫВАЛО еще одну линию не стирая старую.

Comment: смотри update ниже

Answer (score 0):

В вашем исполнении этого не получится. Поскольку отрисовывается метод paint(). У вас в нём case, который выбирает что нарисовать в зависимости от того что ему дают.
  Что бы отрисовать график вам необходимо организовать запоминание координат в List, и уже по этим координатам отрисовывать ваши линии. 
  Лучше всего будет создать отдельный класс для всего этого.

UPDATE

Для построения функции:

- Считываем функцию
- считываем приделы, в которых будет строиться функция
- Парсится функция и прогоняется от одного предела до другого. Так получаются все точки
- Дальше необходим алгоритм по их соединению

Comment: Все бы ничего но этот кусочек кода упрощенная версия программы для графического метода Задач Нелинейного Программирования. Реализация должна быть следующая: В окне выбирается функция, ставятся параметры и по нажатии на кнопку - отрисовывается график, эллепса к примеру. Запомнить все координаты я вообще не представляю как.